# Messy sql problem

Tags: sql

Table A stores data in rows like

```
id, value1, value2
```

where id is always an even number. Table B stores this data in the form

```
id,   value1
id-1, value2
```

or else

```
id,   value1+value2
```

I need to do a once-off update of table B with the values taken from table A.
Are there any elegant ways of doing this?

---

Clarification :

To answer Nate C-K's question below (which gets to the heart of the matter), the only way of knowing which arrangement applies to a record from table A is by inspecting the values(of id) in table B. This is why the problem is messy.

Comment: More specifics please.  Do you just want to take the values in Table A and add them to Table B as shown, or something different?  If the same, then which Table B method do you want to use?

Comment: What do you mean by "or else"? Do you have two different versions to store data in Table B?

Comment: I'm not clear on the system here. Maybe you could give some sample data for each table. How do you determine which arrangement (list both values or list the sum of the values) was used for a given pair of values? And how could you tease apart the original values in the case that column 2 in table B only contains the sum?

Comment: So does your clarification mean that you only sometimes have odd # ids in Table B?

Comment: @Lance : no you can only have the 2 versions shown: (even, odd) or even

Comment: OK, so to clarify, you have two different tables, one with the first layout, and one with the second, and at any one time the code has to handle modifying either table.

Comment: @Lance : No sorry, this is once off-update, of table B from table A. The code doesn't modify table A. It uses data from A to modify B

Comment: Next question, is there always the exact amount of even ids in Table B as there is in Table A?

Comment: @cindi, I meant on the prior clarification that you have two Table B's, and may be running this update on either one without knowing ahead of time which one is to be acted on.

Comment: @Lance : there is only one table B but its like the union of 2 sub tables, and you don't know without inspecting the values of id in  table B which of these sub tables you update

Comment: @Lance : you can't assume  there will always be the  same amount of even ids

Comment: OK, I get it all now, definitely messy, working on it (though I'm not the quick SQL guy so I may get beat on this one).

Comment: looks like with a few fixes cb160s will work, good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the logic you want is the following

- Where id and id - 1 are both in tableb, update both rows
- where no id - 1 row exists, update id with value1 + value 2

Then this should work

```
update b
set b.value = a.value1
from tableb b join tablea a on a.id = b.id
where 0 = a.id % 2
and a.id - 1 in (select id from tableb)

update b
set b.value = a.value2
from tableb b join tablea a on a.id = b.id - 1
where 0 = a.id % 2
and a.id - 1 in (select id from tableb)

update b
set b.value = a.value1 + a.value2
from tableb b join table a on a.id = b.id
and a.id - 1 not in (select id from tableb)
```

Comment: If you are aliasing a, and b and this is sql server this wont work.  As you need to say update AliasName...

Comment: value should sometimes equal value1 + value2

Comment: @cb160, looks good, you probably want to change 'table a' to 'tablea a' for consistency, and you want to change the a.id checks even checks to b.id, since a.id is always even.

Comment: @cb160, and change the tablea in the final select statements to tableb

Comment: @Lance Roberts: Thanks for the tips - updated answer with corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Set B to (id, value1), (id+1, value2) -- latter one only when id+1 exists in B

```
update b
  set b.value = a.value1
  from tableb b join table a on a.id = b.id
  where 0 = a.id % 2

update b
  set b.value = a.value2
  from tableb b join table a on a.id = b.id - 1
  where 0 = a.id % 2
```

Now, for id's where id+1 is not in B, add value2 to the id one.

```
update b
  set b.value += (select a.value2 from a where a.id = b.id)
  where b.id - 1 not in (select id from b)
```

Comment: @Wim, a.id is always even, you want to check against b.id

Answer (score 0):

```
Update b SET b.value1 = a.value1 FROM
TableB b INNER JOIN TableA a ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: value should sometimes equal value1 + value2

Comment: i cant help you because you are not giving us enough data and you are also not giving sample data and expected results. -1 to you

Comment: Sorry its a messy problem, maybe some of the clarification and answers to Lance will help